# How to Sense case and writing in HTML input

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to write a question and options in a text box in the format of a Word file, for example, or text. When I save, I want to bring the question to the table of questions and options to its table. How do I read the text document or the text inside the input line with a line of feeling that the line represents a question or options,
for example:

```
*#Question 1
*Options
*Options
*Options*
```

What is here is how the lines can be listed and their ability to sort by line after line or by word after word.

Comment: Your question in its current state is very unclear. Please state clearly what you want, including input and output examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to access an element inside html. For that you need DOM. The element is the id of the text you are trying to get

```
var element_text = document.getElementById("element").innerHTML
```

Comment: After getting the item I want to segment the content such as fetch the word starting with#

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access the element, just assign it an ID and use `getElementById`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("textBox"));
```

```html
<textarea id="textBox"></textarea>
```

If you want to access its value, use `.value`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("textBox").value);
```

```html
<textarea id="textBox">This is some text!</textarea>
```